# Why has overriding password hashing caused urls to break in magento admin?

Tags: php, magento, url-routing

I have overriden the `hash($data)` and `validateHash($password, $hash)` of `Mage_Core_Model_Encryption` in a custom module. It works I can login to the admin area with my password and it validates correctly with the new hash; however, I cannot navigate in the admin area. I see a password-like hash becomes part of the url:
`admin/dashboard/index/key/[bcrypt hash here]`. The browser cannot redirect to the resulting url. Can anyone advise me on overriding password hashes without breaking the urls with them? Thanks in advance.

In case it helps, my config xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mycompany_Encryption>
      <version>0.1</version>
      <depends>Mage_Core</depends>
    </Mycompany_Encryption>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <core>
        <rewrite>
          <encryption>Mycompany_Encryption_Model_Encryption</encryption>
        </rewrite>
      </core>
    </models>
    <helpers>
      <core>
        <encryption_model>Mycompany_Encryption_Model_Encryption</encryption_model>
      </core>
    </helpers>
  </global>
</config>
```

**UPDATE:**: (per two comments below) how to use password_hash instead of md5 for password authentication, while allowing url keys to use the hash function in an url friendly way?

Comment: Magento do use `core/encryption` to generate key in admin url to avoid Cross Site Request Forgery attacks but will also need to decrypt this encrypted string. Since you overriden it whit a hash (one way, no decrypt possible), Magento admin (and some of the frontend since it is used in form_key also) will not be able to work anymore.

Comment: I see better now that Magento is using 'hash' function for put a key in the url. By default, CE uses md5() (which cannot be decrypted either). It must be caching these hashes and comparing them. The issue seems to be with bcrypt - its hashes may contain '/', '$', '.' and other pernicious characters. I need to make these (bcrypt) hashes work for authentication, to support legacy credentials... but need to have the hash act differently in the url.

Comment: Looks like this project has had to do some workarounds for the same issue (but I haven't delved into it yet): https://github.com/ericthehacker/magento-phpnativepasswords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The encrypt/decrypt functions of `Mage_Core_Model_Encryption` are not used in urls.

Basically, there are two ways to solve the conflict. One being to implement the new hash based on using an event observer on the customer authentication methods. The other method, the one which works better for me is to just extend the `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Url` and override the `getSecretKey` method.
[The two repos linked in comments we helpful in learning this.]

To fix the issue, I added a node to my config.xml inside `models`:

```
<adminhtml>
  <rewrite>
    <url>Mycompany_Encryption_Model_Adminhtml_Url</url>
  </rewrite>
</adminhtml>
```

And then added the file `Mycompany/Encryption/Model/Adminhtml/Url.php`:

```
class Mycompany_Encryption_Model_Adminhtml_Url extends Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Url
{
    public function getSecretKey($controller = null, $action = null)
    {
        $salt = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();
        $p = explode('/', trim($this->getRequest()->getOriginalPathInfo(), '/'));

        if (!$controller) {
            $controller = !empty($p[1]) ? $p[1] : $this->getRequest()->getControllerName();
        }

        if (!$action) {
             $action = !empty($p[2]) ? $p[2] : $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
        }
        $secret = $controller . $action . $salt;

        // Overriding getHash() to use a diff hash than passwords.
         return Mage::helper('core')->getEncryptor()->urlHash($secret);
    }
}
```

Lastly, I updated my `Mycompany/Encryption/Model/Encryption.php` by adding a urlHash method (in addition to the `hash`, `validateHash`, and `getHash` function already located there):

```
public function urlHash($value)
{
    return md5($value);
}
```

I could have just returned `md5($secret)` at the end of `getSecretKey` and that works also, but this method demonstrates more Mage methods that are helpful to see in action.

I have not fully tested my module yet, but this appears to be fully compatible with every place getSecretKey is called.

Comment: There is still a bug with this answer... in logging into the admin, am needing to clear cache (via command line), the refresh page twice after initial admin login.

Comment: OP had an error in the helpers node of the config. I'll edit and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I did a little bit of research in the core files and it looks like the way to achieve what you want to achieve is possible via a factory.

Sadly, it looks like Magento did part of the job but not all.

**Mage_Core_Model_Encryption::_getCrypt($key = null)**

```
protected function _getCrypt($key = null)
{
    if (!$this->_crypt) {
        if (null === $key) {
            $key = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/crypt/key');
        }
        $this->_crypt = Varien_Crypt::factory()->init($key);
    }
    return $this->_crypt;
}
```

**Varien_Crypt** which make me said that is not done in full, that is a factory, but it is called with no params in the function above, so, yes, no way to change the object returned by the factory, sigh.

```
class Varien_Crypt
{
    static public function factory($method='mcrypt')
    {
        $uc = str_replace(' ','_',ucwords(str_replace('_',' ',$method)));
        $className = 'Varien_Crypt_'.$uc;
        return new $className;
    }
}
```

But then knowing those two are designed like that you could : override `Varien_Crypt` to have another class instantiated and based on the method of the class `Varien_Crypt_Mcrypt`, implement the same methods and get what you want to achieve working.

And by looking at this, I also found someone posting on the magento Q&A of stack exchange his module to have a more secure password encryption.
It is under a BSD licence on GitHub so [here is his post on the network](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/10003)
and [here is the module, called pbkdf2, repository](https://github.com/ikonoshirt/pbkdf2)

Maybe you could find something helpful in the way he implemented it (I did not take time to look at his code, tough).